# Reading database data and forwarding to variables

Tags: c#, sql, .net, generic-list

Can anyone point me to where I make a mistake, I want to put a new sql query where I will read the data from the database and put them in my function, and in the end they will be displayed at the exit in the colon ("stunden") which currently appears on the first query *`SUM (zei.ZPZ_Std100) AS ZPZ_Std100`*

This looks like my entire code in the button

```
using (SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestControl.Properties.Settings.DB"].ConnectionString))
        {
            boAPI4.Login login = new boAPI4.Login();
            string cS = login.GetConnectionString();
            DataAccess dA = new DataAccess(cS);
            int userID = dA.getLpeID(login.GetBoUserNr());
            PRAESENZZEIT q = new PRAESENZZEIT();

            q.ZPZ_LPE_ID = userID;
            if (db.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                db.Open();
            string query = "SELECT per.LPE_Nr, zei.ZPZ_LPE_ID, zei.ZPZ_Datum, SUM (zei.ZPZ_Std100) AS ZPZ_Std100" +
                           " FROM DB.dbo.Z_PRAESENZZEIT zei INNER JOIN DB.dbo.A_PERSONAL per ON zei.ZPZ_LPE_ID = per.LPE_ID" +
                            $" WHERE zei.ZPZ_Datum BETWEEN '{dtFromDate.Value}' AND '{dtToDate.Value}' AND zei.ZPZ_LPE_ID='{userID.ToString()}' GROUP BY per.LPE_Nr, zei.ZPZ_LPE_ID, zei.ZPZ_Datum ORDER BY zei.ZPZ_Datum, per.LPE_Nr;";

            pRAESENZZEITBindingSource.DataSource = db.Query<PRAESENZZEIT>(query, commandType: CommandType.Text);

            List<PRAESENZZEIT> listid = new List<PRAESENZZEIT>();
            PRAESENZZEIT pra = new PRAESENZZEIT();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestControl.Properties.Settings.DB"].ConnectionString);
            string sql = "SELECT ZPZ_Von,ZPZ_bis FROM  DB.dbo.Z_PRAESENZZEIT WHERE ZPZ_LPE_ID='196'";
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                pra.ZPZ_Von = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["ZPZ_Von"]);
                pra.ZPZ_Bis = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["ZPZ_bis"]);
                listid.Add(pra);
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = listid;
            con.Close();

            DateTime kommen = DateTime.Now;

            kommen = pra.ZPZ_Von;
            if (pra.ZPZ_Von.TimeOfDay < new TimeSpan(8, 5, 0))
                pra.ZPZ_Von = new DateTime(pra.ZPZ_Von.Year, pra.ZPZ_Von.Month, pra.ZPZ_Von.Day, 8, 0, 0);

            DateTime gehen = DateTime.Now;
            gehen = pra.ZPZ_Bis;
            TimeSpan arbeitszeit = pra.ZPZ_Bis - pra.ZPZ_Von;

        }
```

Currently, at the exit I get 0.

[image]

So, I need data that pass through the datetime variable

This is how it goes through the variables but returns the result as if it did not address base data, what's the problem? I understand if time [ZPZ_VON 07:45] that the exit should be 08:00..

**SQL QUERY**   *SELECT ZPZ_Von,ZPZ_bis FROM  DB.dbo.Z_PRAESENZZEIT WHERE ZPZ_LPE_ID='196'*

CODE:

```
 List<PRAESENZZEIT> listid = new List<PRAESENZZEIT>();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestControl.Properties.Settings.DB"].ConnectionString);
            string sql = "SELECT ZPZ_Von, ZPZ_bis FROM  DB.dbo.Z_PRAESENZZEIT WHERE ZPZ_LPE_ID='196'";
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();


            while (dr.Read())
            {
                PRAESENZZEIT pra = new PRAESENZZEIT();
                pra.ZPZ_Von = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["ZPZ_Von"]);
                pra.ZPZ_Bis = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["ZPZ_bis"]);
                listid.Add(pra);

                DateTime kommen = DateTime.Now;

                kommen = pra.ZPZ_Von;
                if (pra.ZPZ_Von.TimeOfDay < new TimeSpan(8, 5, 0))
                    pra.ZPZ_Von = new DateTime(pra.ZPZ_Von.Year, pra.ZPZ_Von.Month, pra.ZPZ_Von.Day, 8, 0, 0);

                DateTime gehen = DateTime.Now;
                gehen = pra.ZPZ_Bis;
                TimeSpan arbeitszeit = pra.ZPZ_Bis - pra.ZPZ_Von;
            }
            con.Close();
```

DATABASE QUERY RESULT:

[image: look at the photo]

Comment: Never ever concatenate strings to pass parameters. Use parameteried queries. Your approach can cause sql injection or slow/wrong queries.

Comment: `PRAESENZZEIT pra = new PRAESENZZEIT();`  needs to be inside `while` loop

Comment: @BALAgurunathanMarimuthu where would be PRAESENZZEIT pra = new PRAESENZZEIT(); needs to be inside

Comment: @BalagurunathanMarimuthu   have corrected myself, I put up in question my discussion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were initializing the `pra` class outside the `while` loop. Which doesn't add new record in the list `listid` every time read `DataRow` from `DataReader`.

Try this below code:

```
using (SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestControl.Properties.Settings.DB"].ConnectionString))
{
    boAPI4.Login login = new boAPI4.Login();
    string cS = login.GetConnectionString();
    DataAccess dA = new DataAccess(cS);
    int userID = dA.getLpeID(login.GetBoUserNr());
    PRAESENZZEIT q = new PRAESENZZEIT();

    q.ZPZ_LPE_ID = userID;
    if (db.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        db.Open();
    string query = "SELECT per.LPE_Nr, zei.ZPZ_LPE_ID, zei.ZPZ_Datum, SUM (zei.ZPZ_Std100) AS ZPZ_Std100" +
                   " FROM DB.dbo.Z_PRAESENZZEIT zei INNER JOIN DB.dbo.A_PERSONAL per ON zei.ZPZ_LPE_ID = per.LPE_ID" +
                    $" WHERE zei.ZPZ_Datum BETWEEN '{dtFromDate.Value}' AND '{dtToDate.Value}' AND zei.ZPZ_LPE_ID='{userID.ToString()}' GROUP BY per.LPE_Nr, zei.ZPZ_LPE_ID, zei.ZPZ_Datum ORDER BY zei.ZPZ_Datum, per.LPE_Nr;";

    pRAESENZZEITBindingSource.DataSource = db.Query<PRAESENZZEIT>(query, commandType: CommandType.Text);

    List<PRAESENZZEIT> listid = new List<PRAESENZZEIT>();
    //PRAESENZZEIT pra = new PRAESENZZEIT(); //Needs to be inside the while loop.
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestControl.Properties.Settings.DB"].ConnectionString);
    string sql = "SELECT ZPZ_Von,ZPZ_bis FROM  DB.dbo.Z_PRAESENZZEIT WHERE ZPZ_LPE_ID='196'";
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    var listid = ConvertDataTable<PRAESENZZEIT>(dt);

    dataGridView1.DataSource = listid;
    con.Close();
}

private static List<T> ConvertDataTable<T>(DataTable dt)  
{  
   List<T> data = newList<T>();  
   foreach (DataRowrow in dt.Rows)  
   {  
      Titem = GetItem<T>(row);  
      data.Add(item);  
   }  
   return data;  
}  

private static TGetItem<T>(DataRow dr)  
{  
   Type temp = typeof(T);  
   T obj =Activator.CreateInstance<T>();  
   foreach (DataColumncolumn in dr.Table.Columns)  
   {  
      foreach (PropertyInfopro in temp.GetProperties())  
      {  
         if (pro.Name == column.ColumnName)  
         pro.SetValue(obj,dr[column.ColumnName], null);  
         else  
         continue;  
      }  
   }  
   return obj;  
}
```

Comment: it again throws me out at the exit, as in the picture above .. but when I skim the loop while, it does work normally to me .. but I want it to go through this time and to give me back what I put down.

Comment: Instead of `DataReader` try to get the data to `DataTable` and convert it into `Generic List` as you want.

Comment: thanks a lot to my friend, but i can not get this kind of code to fix it ..

Comment: You are welcome. If you need this in future then just use it. It seems of `Generic` functions when we use different `List<T>`. :)